# Copying the contents from a sheet based on a value to another using vba but the value is being overwritten

Tags: vba

Have below VBA code wherein I am trying to copy the US, developer and date from "P1" sheet to "sheet2" based on the project(i.e. column A)

Below is the code that I am using but I see that the value in the cell is being overwritten as part of loop, could you please help

```
Sub transfer()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, lastrow1 As Long, longrow2 As Long, lastrow3 As Long

Dim myname As String
lastrow1 = Sheets("P1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
myname = Sheets("P1").Cells(i, "A").Value

Sheets("sheet2").Activate
lastrow2 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow2
        If Sheets("sheet2").Cells(j, "A").Value = myname Then
        Sheets("P1").Activate
        Sheets("P1").Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "D")).Copy
         Sheets("sheet2").Activate
         Sheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(j, "B"), Cells(j, "D")).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste                

        End If    
       Next j

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

Sheets("P1").Activate
Sheets("P1").Range("A1").Select            
End Sub
```

[Posted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVRWz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not very good practice to use `Selection`, `Copy` and `Paste` options in VBA. Try to use `Values` instead. Try something like this:

```
Sub transfer()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, lastrow1 As Long, longrow2 As Long, lastrow3 As Long

Dim myname As String
lastrow1 = Sheets("P1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
myname = Sheets("P1").Cells(i, "A").Value

Sheets("sheet2").Activate
lastrow2 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow2
        If Sheets("sheet2").Cells(j, "A").Value = myname Then
        Sheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(i, "B").Value = Sheets("P1").Range(Cells(i, "B").Value
        Sheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(i, "D").Value = Sheets("P1").Range(Cells(i, "D").Value

                       End If

       Next j

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

End Sub
```

This is not exactly the way that I would do it, but this should work integrated with your code. If you would like me to post how I would code this particular issue, feel free to ask. (I actually just did something like this for work a few days ago)